# Simple user accounts in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, user-accounts

In previous versions of Windows, I could have created mulitple accounts for my family members to have their settings. Now, I do not understand anyting. My father got a PC with windows 10 and single Lenovo account with blank password. I tried to add myself to leave his settings intact. I had to enter my email/password. Now, it renamed the Lenovo account to my name and asks for my password in Windows log-in. Furthermore, I do not have the email for my father, to make him a separate account. How do I reset the need for my password and fall back to simple local accounts, as it used to be in pre-Win10 era?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Manage your account would do this.

Type that into the start menu

[image: ![enter image description here]

You can use that to convert your "cloud" windows/MS login into a local one

[image]

To create a new account without a networked login you go to family and other people.

[image][image]

Comment: I tried that and, obviously, your suggestion to choose "I do not have the account" redirects you to the "create the cloud account" dialog with no other options.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/instantanswers/5de907f1-f8ba-4fd9-a89d-efd23fee918c/create-a-local-user-account-in-windows-10 seems to back me up.

Comment: And what should I do?

Comment: Added one more screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

There is another way. Do Right-click the Start to Computer Management > Local Users > New User.

[image]

Once created, use user properties to add them to Administrators.